# Crop image with OpenCV c++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, crop

How may I crop images in OpenCV C++ ?

There are images as below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have the `rect` using which you want to crop the input image

Comment: yes , but  i don't know the area , how to get the coordinate

Comment: the first image is source image , and i want get the second image crop from the first image.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it needs some algorithms for detecting Region-of-Interest (ROI). If you sure that's only black and white, you can directly use the threshold to detect the first point from the first row of the source image.

Then, you can just use `Rect` to corp the source image and `copyTo` result image.